# Have an error running one PowerShell script to concatenate avi files, when a very similar script works fine

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg

When I run the following PowerShell script, to concatenate the .avi files in a folder, I get an error.

Script:

```
# Set the folder path where the AVI files are located
$folderPath = "C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam"

# Get all AVI files in the folder
$aviFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*.avi" | Sort-Object Name

# Check if there are at least 2 AVI files for concatenation
if ($aviFiles.Count -ge 2) {
    $videoFiles = $aviFiles.FullName

    Write-Host "Input Files for Concatenation:"
    foreach ($file in $aviFiles) {
        Write-Host $file.Name
    }

    $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath "concatenated.avi"

    # Create the FFmpeg command for concatenation
    $concatArguments = "-f", "concat", "-i", "`"concat:$videoFiles`"", "-c", "copy", "`"$outputFile`""

    $command = "ffmpeg $concatArguments"
    Write-Host "FFmpeg Command: $command"

    try {
        $process = Start-Process -FilePath "ffmpeg" -ArgumentList $concatArguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Concatenation complete. Output file: $outputFile"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error occurred while executing FFmpeg command:"
        Write-Host "Error message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Not enough AVI files found in the folder for concatenation."
}
```

Output with error, (and no concatenated file is actually produced, needless to say):

```
Input Files for Concatenation:
webcam0.avi
webcam1.avi
FFmpeg Command: ffmpeg -f concat -i "concat:C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\webcam0.avi C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\webcam1.avi" -c copy "C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\concatenated.avi"
ffmpeg version 2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavcodec     60. 21.100 / 60. 21.100
  libavformat    60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  8.102 /  9.  8.102
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[in#0 @ 000001d2f05f1b00] Error opening input: Invalid argument
Concatenation complete. Output file: C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\concatenated.avi
```

But this script, which ostensibly does the same thing to the same files, works fine:

```
$file1 = "C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\webcam0.avi"       # Path to the first video file
$file2 = "C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\webcam1.avi"       # Path to the second video file
$outputFile = "C:\Users\HomePC\hswlab\Desktop\videos\eyeblink\022223\2023_04_24\16_15_23\My_WebCam\concat.avi"  # Path to the output concatenated video file

# Create a temporary batch script
$batchScriptPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + ".bat"
@'
@echo off
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -i "%~2" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" "%~3"
'@ | Set-Content -Path $batchScriptPath

# Execute the temporary batch script
try {
    & $batchScriptPath $file1 $file2 $outputFile
    Write-Host "Concatenation complete. Output file: $outputFile"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error occurred while executing FFmpeg command:"
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}

# Remove the temporary batch script
Remove-Item -Path $batchScriptPath -Force
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the first script. I tried many variations of the first script but cannot get it to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) documentation page:

- You must use *either* the `concat` *subcommand* OR the `concat:` *protocol*, to which you pass a list of file paths *separated with `|`*.

Therefore:

```bash
ffmpeg -f -i ('concat:' + ($videoFiles -join '|')) -c copy $outputFile
# Use $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 to test for failure.
```

Note the use of *direct invocation* of `ffmpeg`, which *by default* runs in the same window and synchronously, and additionally allows you to capture any output, while reflecting the process exit code in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

An additional benefit of direct invocation is that you don't have to worry about explicit quoting of arguments - PowerShell does that for you (if an argument contains spaces, it is automatically enclosed in `"..."` on the process command line constructed behind the scenes).

For invocation of *console* applications such as `ffmpeg`, [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) is rarely the right tool - see [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.